# Element, that describe level of importance

Tags: info-visualisation, help, ui-element

I'm working a website design.

I have a table with products from my list (like basket in eCommerce websites), and table with information about shops (address, link to map etc.), where I can buy products which I selected.

The result of table with shops depends on level of importance of each product from my list.

So, I need to create custom element like level importance select. There are 3 levels of importance: not important, normal (or standard importance) and high importance.

The first thing that came to mind it's create a range selector with 3 positions, but this solution means 2 clicks:

1. user click to selector.
2. user drag to needed position.

It's not good for me.

Now, I stopped on other solution. I want to draw 3 rectangles:

1. First rectangle means "not important level".
2. Second rectangle means "normal important level". This rectangle will selected by default.
3. Third rectangle means "high importance level".

As a result, user should make 1 click to select needed level. Each rectangle will has own color: first - grey, second - green, third - red.

Can you help me with new ideas? Maybe exist much easy solution?

Comment: This sounds very much like you want the rectangles to behave like radio buttons. So why not use radio buttons? They seem perfect for this.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest you to use star ratings. It would be more intuitive and the same star rating interface can also be used to convey the importance as well as getting input on importance.

It can also provide good visual feedback to your user by showing, for example, 2.5 colored starts and remaining as grayed out.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you think a star rating is best? Do you have sources that say it would be best?

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I would not have preferred to select star as the icon, because, star icon means something like rating (in my case it's another thing than importance) or action like "Add to favorites".

Comment: A star rating would confuse the user, since it is usually used for other types of ratings.